# Laravel using UNION in query builder

Tags: php, sql, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I have an SQL query that works fine and I'm trying to convert into fluent::

```
SELECT DISTINCT tags.tag
  FROM tags, items
  WHERE tags.taggable_type = 'Item'
  AND items.item_list_id = '1'
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT tags.tag
  FROM tags, itemlists
  WHERE tags.taggable_type = 'ItemList'
  AND itemlists.id = '1'
```

This is what I have so far in fluent, it all seems right as far as I can tell from the docs and the individual queries both work on their own, it's just when I UNION them it throws an error:

```
   $itemTags = Tag::join('items', 'items.id', '=', 'tags.taggable_id')
                ->select('tags.tag')
                ->distinct()
                ->where('tags.taggable_type', '=', 'Item')
                ->where('items.item_list_id', '=', $itemList->id);

    $itemListTags = Tag::join('itemlists', 'itemlists.id', '=', 'tags.taggable_id')
                ->select('tags.tag')
                ->distinct()
                ->where('tags.taggable_type', '=', 'ItemList')
                ->where('itemlists.id', '=', $itemList->id);
// the var_dump below shows the expected results for the individual queries
// var_dump($itemTags->lists('tag'), $itemListTags->lists('tag')); exit;
    return      $itemTags
                ->union($itemListTags)
                ->get();
```

I get the following error when I run it (I've also swapped from Ardent back to Eloquent on the model in case that made a difference - it doesn't):

```
Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::mergeBindings() must be an instance of Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder, instance of LaravelBook\Ardent\Builder given, called in path/to/root\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder.php on line 898 and defined
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like your models are using Ardent, not Eloquent:

```
...instance of LaravelBook\Ardent\Builder given, ...
```

And probably this might be a problem on Ardent, not Laravel.

Open an issue here: https://github.com/laravelbook/ardent.

EDIT:

Try to change use QueryBuilder instead of Eloquent:

Use this for QueryBuilder:

```
DB::table('tags')->
```

Instead of the Eloquent way:

```
Tag::
```

Comment: Hi, I've tried setting all three models to extend Eloquent not Ardent I I get a similar error: `Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::mergeBindings() must be an instance of Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder, instance of Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder given, called in E:\docs\Documents\Work\MGC\mgc_root\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder.php on line 898 and defined `

Comment: Are you using Laravel 4.0 or 4.1?

Comment: 4.0 I believe, I'll try running a composer update to see if that helps

Comment: Edited, might work using QueryBuilder. But this looks like a bug on Laravel.

Comment: I'm on 4.0 the composer.json file has : `"laravel/framework": "4.0.*",`, I've run a composer update. Guess I'll file a bug report, thanks.

Comment: Did you saw my edit? Tested using QueryBuilder instead of Eloquent?

Comment: Hi, just noticed it. That does seem to work - strange! Is that a bug that should be reported do you think or should I close the bug request I opened on github. Thanks!!

Comment: Keep it. There's a problem on Eloquen/QueryBuilder.

Comment: No problem. Enjoy Laravel! :)

Comment: I got the same issue, anyway this is because `mergeBindings()` function expect an instance of `Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder` instead of `Ardent\Builder` or `Eloquent\Builder`... as you said before. So `DB::table('tags')` can replace `Tag` just for variable `$itemListTags` sent to `union()` function. I said that because sometimes (as in my case) you need Eloquent or Ardent for the first object ( as `$itemTags` in this case ), and this can stay `Eloquent` or `Ardent`. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

I know you mentioned wanting to use the query builder, but for complex queries that the builder might throw fits on, you can directly access the PDO object:

```
$pdo = DB::connection()->getPdo();
```