# Laravel Eloquent Join vs Inner Join?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have a user and they go to their feed page, on this page it shows stuff from their friends (friends votes, friends comments, friends status updates). So say I have tom, tim and taylor as my friends and I need to get all of their votes, comments, status updates. How do I go about this? I have a list of all the friends by Id number, and I have tables for each of the events (votes, comments, status updates) that have the Id stored in it to link back to the user. So how can I get all of that information at once so that I can display it in a feed in the form of.

> Tim commented "Cool"
>
> Taylor Said "Woot first status update~!"
>
> Taylor Voted on "Best competition ever"

I would prefer to do this in the database because mysql sorting thousands of records in order is 100x faster then php taking 3 lists, merging them and then doing it. Any ideas?

Comment: How are you storing this `list of all the friends by Id number`.... is it in a `friends` table, or is it a comma-separated list in a column in your `users` table? If the latter, then normalise your database so that you can then use model relationships (hasManyThrough())

Comment: You can create a view in your db, and an Eloquent `model` for it. Then just get all the events you want. Otherwise you could use `polymorphic` relations: laravel.com/docs/eloquent#polymorphic-relations

Comment: please don't add the right answer to the original question, it becomes all blurry then

Comment: Your last comment sums it up, direct sql is orders of magnitude faster than clunky eloquent and orm querying, which ironically becomes more complicated than standard sql anyway.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

I'm sure there are other ways to accomplish this, but one solution would be to use `join` through the Query Builder.

If you have tables set up something like this:

```
users
    id
    ...

friends
    id
    user_id
    friend_id
    ...

votes, comments and status_updates (3 tables)
    id
    user_id
    ....
```

In your **User** model:

```
class User extends Eloquent {
    public function friends()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Friend');
    }
}
```

In your **Friend** model:

```
class Friend extends Eloquent {
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('User');
    }
}
```

Then, to gather all the votes for the friends of the user with the id of 1, you could run this query:

```
$user = User::find(1);
$friends_votes = $user->friends()
    ->with('user') // bring along details of the friend
    ->join('votes', 'votes.user_id', '=', 'friends.friend_id')
    ->get(['votes.*']); // exclude extra details from friends table
```

Run the same `join` for the `comments` and `status_updates` tables. If you would like votes, comments, and status_updates to be in one chronological list, you can merge the resulting three collections into one and then sort the merged collection.

---

**Edit**

To get votes, comments, and status updates in one query, you could build up each query and then union the results. Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to work if we use the Eloquent `hasMany` relationship ([see comments for this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19050387/laravel-using-union-in-query-builder) for a discussion of that problem) so we have to modify to queries to use `where` instead:

```
$friends_votes = 
    DB::table('friends')->where('friends.user_id','1')
    ->join('votes', 'votes.user_id', '=', 'friends.friend_id');

$friends_comments = 
    DB::table('friends')->where('friends.user_id','1')
    ->join('comments', 'comments.user_id', '=', 'friends.friend_id');

$friends_status_updates = 
    DB::table('status_updates')->where('status_updates.user_id','1')
    ->join('friends', 'status_updates.user_id', '=', 'friends.friend_id');

$friends_events = 
    $friends_votes
    ->union($friends_comments)
    ->union($friends_status_updates)
    ->get();
```

At this point, though, our query is getting a bit hairy, so a polymorphic relationship with and an extra table (like DefiniteIntegral suggests below) might be a better idea.

Comment: Maybe I am doing something wrong, but If I run this code I end up getting all the information for the user with id 1, rather then the friends info.

Comment: With some adjustments I eventually got this to work, so you said if I wanted to get comments, status updates etc I should run separate calls, is there a way to get all of them at once?

Comment: I edited the answer to include code that would get all 3 at once, using `union`.

Comment: It really baffles me that Eloquent and ORM's in general make querying databases SO MUCH more complicated than standard SQL, and also *SO MUCH* less efficient. And most people blindly accept this... Perhaps I'm just stuck in my ways (of exponentially faster/more efficient SQL)

Answer (score 5):

Probably not what you want to hear, but a "feeds" table would be a great middleman for this sort of transaction, giving you a denormalized way of pivoting to all these data with a polymorphic relationship.

You could build it like this:

```
<?php

Schema::create('feeds', function($table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->timestamps();
    $table->unsignedInteger('user_id');
    $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
    $table->morphs('target'); 
});
```

Build the feed model like so:

```
<?php

class Feed extends Eloquent
{
    protected $fillable = ['user_id', 'target_type', 'target_id'];

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('User');
    }

    public function target()
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }
}
```

Then keep it up to date with something like:

```
<?php

Vote::created(function(Vote $vote) {
    $target_type = 'Vote';
    $target_id   = $vote->id;
    $user_id     = $vote->user_id;

    Feed::create(compact('target_type', 'target_id', 'user_id'));
});
```

You could make the above much more generic/robust—this is just for demonstration purposes.

At this point, your feed items are really easy to retrieve all at once:

```
<?php

Feed::whereIn('user_id', $my_friend_ids)
    ->with('user', 'target')
    ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
    ->get();
```

Comment: Note also...technically, you could do this with a union query, if you are morally opposed to the additional table. Personally, I think denormalization is a powerful technique for situations like this...the UNION version is going to be much gnarlier.