# How to get data to table that has many relationships in Eloquent

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, eloquent

I am trying to work on an eloquent model Post where it has two hasOne relationships: `offer_post` and `request_post`.

Post.php

```php
class Post extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $table = 'tbl_post';
    protected $fillable = ['email', 'postIdentity', 'postStatus'];

    public $timestamps = false;
    public $primaryKey = 'indexPost';

    public static function boot()
    {
    parent::boot();
    self::creating(function ($model) {
        $model->postNumber = (string) Uuid::generate(4);
    });
    }

    public function pasabuy_user() {
        $this->belongsTo(PasabuyUser::class, 'email', 'email');
    }

    public function offer_post() {
        return $this->hasOne(OfferPost::class, 'postNumber', 'postNumber');
    }

    public function request_post() {
        return $this->hasOne(RequestPost::class, 'postNumber', 'postNumber');
    }
}
```

OfferPost.php

```php
class OfferPost extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $table = 'tbl_shoppingOfferPost';
    protected $fillable = ['postNumber', 'postStatus', 'deliveryArea', 'shoppingPlace', 'deliverySchedule', 'transportMode', 'capacity', 'paymentMethod', 'caption'];

    public $timestamps = false;
    public $primaryKey = 'indexShoppingOfferPost';

    public function post() {
        return $this->belongsTo(Post::class, 'postNumber', 'postNumber');
    }
}
```

RequestPost.php

```php
class RequestPost extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $table = 'tbl_orderRequestPost';
    protected $fillable = [
        'postNumber',
        'postStatus',
        'deliveryAddress',
        'shoppingPlace',
        'deliverySchedule',
        'paymentMethod',
        'shoppingList',
        'caption'
    ];

    public $timestamps = false;
    public $primaryKey = 'indexOrderRequestPost';

    /**
     *    [post description]
     *    @author Al Vincent Musa
     *    @return [type] [description]
     */
    public function post() {
        return $this->belongsTo(Post::class, 'postNUmber', 'postNumber');       
    }
}
```

This is how my tables looks like. [image]

Now I want to get all post(both offer post and request post)
Get offer post like

```sql
SELECT from tbl_post INNER JOIN tbl_shoppingOfferPost ON tbl_post.postNumber = tbl_shoppingOfferPost.postNumber
```

and likewise for the request post.

I came as far as

```php
$post = Post::has('offer_post')->get();
```

but this only returns data from tbl_post. But want both from tbl_post  and tbl_shoppingOfferPost.
I am having a hard time understanding the docs. I don't know where to start. Any help is much appreciated. I just need a pointer where to look at. Thanks

Comment: You have a very strange and cuestionable table names and definitions... none uses `id`, or have timestamps ? You are going to have problems if you do not follow the "Laravel Way". Please read the docs about how to use the framework because you are going to have a lot of headaches...

Comment: I did not design the database. As much as I wanted to use the laravel way. They said that will use Laravel but they don't use Laravel on how it is supposed to be used. I don't want to make a fuss about it.

Comment: Oh god... good luck with them, then... That is a disaster...

Answer (score 2):

You can do like this

```
$post::with(['offer_post','request_post'])->get();
```

Comment: I have found a related question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25984226/laravel-eloquent-join-vs-inner-join

I will try the solutions.But if anyone has a better way to do it. Please let me know. Thanks

Comment: @AlVincentMusa This is the correct way of doing it, do not use the related question's answer.